# Android: Text in custom textView not centering

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have the following layout file. I want to center the text in the second textView. In Android Studio design preview the text is centered. However, on running the app it is off the center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <com.my.app.MyCustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_text_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.my.app.MyCustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/custome_text_2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

This is how it looks (0 is not in the center)

[image]

Strangely though, if I replace my custom textView with just `TextView` the text is perfectly centered now.

[image]

This is the `MyCustomTextView`

```
public class MyCustomTextView extends TextView {
    public MyCustomTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public MyCustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public MyCustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyCustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initView();
    }

//here the typeface is set on the TextView after creating typeface from font asset
    private void initView() {
        CommonUtils.setCustomFontForText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), MyCustomTextView.this);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? What is going wrong here? Thanks!!

Comment: The font looks different in the two images. May just be that?

Comment: @devgianlu They are different fonts.

Comment: There's your problem. The font has a bit of padding on the bottom and that causes the misalignment. Try adding a negative padding to the view or use the same font as the ok one.